# Child theme functions.php not executing

Tags: functions, child-theme

I have the following in a child theme's functions.php file:

```
<?php

function theme_child_add_scripts() {
    wp_register_script(
        'script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        null,
        false
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script' )
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_child_add_scripts');
```

script.js isn't included on the page and there's no network request going out to get it. What could be going wrong? It's unclear whether the child theme's functions.php file is even being executed.

edit: It seems that the functions.php file is not being executed *at all*, because I put a die('foo') at the top of the file and the page loaded normally. Why would this be happening?

In styles.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: Theme-child
Template: Theme
*/
```

Comment: The parent them is correctly defined in the child's style.css?

Comment: When the template in the child's style.css is Theme-child, the functions.php file is found and executed. However, this displays an error in the admin panel that the parent theme could not be found.

Comment: `Template` should match the directory name of the parent. That's usually lowercase.

Comment: It's uppercase in this scenario--just double-checked to confirm.

Comment: Is your child theme Activated in the back end?

Comment: I believe so--it's loading child styles correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our problem was that our style.css file was in a css folder inside the child theme directory, not at the root of the child theme. When we placed a style.css file at the root and included the comment block with theme name and template it picked up the functions.php file as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with a code that executed perfectly in the theme functions.php but not in the child theme's (that's how I found this page). I found a non-tech solution, using the free plug in Code Snippets the code executed perfectly. I was looking for a php solution, but this has saved me a bit of time.